# Can't import CardboardActivity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cardboard

When trying to create a new Google Cardboard app, I'm unable to get my app to import the cardboard.jar and recognize CardboardActivity. I have placed `cardboard.jar` and `libprotobuf-java-2.6-nano.jar` in the libs directory and build.gradle includes the line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` as a dependency. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking `cardboard.jar` and selecting "Add As Library..." will actually add the package to the project.